# How to Restart Spring boot application (or just a particular instance of a class) when flyway migrate is ran or a new schema version is added

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I have a particular instance of a class that loads some data from the database, so every time the database is updated the system should recreate the instance of that class to get the updated data

Answer (score 0):

There are trivial several solutions:
(1) Use scheduling to load the latest data from DB periodically.
(2) Provide a web service such as RESTful API to load the latest data from DB.
(3) If your DB supports event-driven listeners, you can trigger your application to achieve this either by invoking a service described in (2) or send a message to queue and handle it by consumer.